# Paid Version?Is it Real?

Tags: release-freya, elementary-website, download

i know this is a newbie question but i am a newbie to this OS, i heard from my some sort of friend that if i donate a certain money to elementary OS community you will receive a SPECIAL VERSION of elementary i just wanted to know that is it true? or not?because I paid and no download happened - how can I fix this? I followed the basic capture routine of Open OS that you can't download without a Credit Card.!

Comment: please check before posting your question posed before, many of times it is asked before. help to avoid duplicates.