# How can I (re-)download without paying (again)?

Tags: elementary-website, download

While I did / do not mind supporting your efforts, I am not really in favor of paying again if I need to download elementary again, for instance for a clean reinstall, or just to always have the current release on hand in full form.

How can I download without paying again?

Comment: Kudos for donating. In future you can enter $0 as a 'custom amount'.

Comment: Also see https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/paid-versionis-it-real?lq=1

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate of those questions, since it's specifically how to download without paying. Neither of those questions ask or answer that.

Comment: I was afraid this would happen - that people would think the payment is mandatory. (Of course we all know elementary needs money, don't get me wrong.)

Comment: @LewisGoddard I too not sure but [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/paid-versionis-it-real?lq=1) both answers explained I think

Comment: @Ravan I've merged those questions since they were well established duplicates, so now we have both answers on the original, but I still think the questions themselves are different, even if the result is the same.

Comment: @LewisGoddard good decision to merge. I agree with you and retracted my vote :)

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, thank you very much for supporting development by purchasing a copy of elementary OS. It's our primary source of income and the vast majority of people choose to never pay anything. So we really appreciate your initial payment.

If you ever need to re-download elementary OS, you can always click the "custom" button and type in "0". This will completely bypass the payment dialog.

However, I do please ask that for new versions you consider a small payment. Without continued funding, our development pace and infrastructure will be impacted.

Comment: Are you part of the elementary team?

Comment: @SuiciDoga Yes, I'm the founder of elementary